# Explicit solution to the PDE $-\Delta u= 2\pi^2 sen(\pi y ) sen(\pi x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let $\Omega=(0,1)\times (0,1)$, I need to find all $u\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ solutions to the following PDE
>   $$-\Delta u= 2\pi^2 sen(\pi y ) sen(\pi x)$$
>   such that $u=0$ in $\partial \Omega$.

I haven't solve explicitly any PDE before so I don't know the difficulty of this problem. 
I would really appreciate any solution or hint.

Edit: The problem said to solve this equation along with the equation
$$-\Delta v= \pi^2 sen(2\pi y ) sen(2\pi x)$$ also satisfying $v=0$ in $\partial \Omega$.

Probably the first equation is easier if you think it together with this one.

Comment: What is $sen$? $\phantom{}$

Comment: @UmbertoP. The sine function in spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for either equation, if you find one solution, then by uniqueness, you have found all solutions. The standard argument for uniqueness goes like this: suppose that $w_1, w_2$ both satisfy the equation $$-\triangle u = f \,\,\,\, \text{ in } \Omega, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, u = 0 \,\,\,\, \text{ on } \partial \Omega.$$ Then the difference $w = w_1 - w_2$ satisfies $$-\triangle w = 0 \,\,\,\, \text{ in } \Omega, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, w = 0 \,\,\,\, \text{ on } \partial \Omega.$$ Thus $$-w\triangle w = 0 \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\, -\int_\Omega w \triangle w dx = 0 \,\,\,\, \implies \int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla w \rvert^2 dx - \int_{partial \Omega} w \frac{\partial w}{\partial n} dS(x) = 0$$ where the last implication follows from integration by parts. However, the boundary term disappears since $w$ is zero on the boundary. Thus $$\int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla w \rvert^2 dx = 0 \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, \nabla w = 0 \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, w = \text{ constant}.$$ However, the constant must be zero due to the boundary condition so $w =0$ and $w_1 = w_2$ proving uniqueness.

I assume that by $sen(X)$, you mean $\sin(X)$. In this case, you can solve both of these simply by looking for solutions in the form of the forcing functions. For the first, suppose that $$u(x,y) = \alpha \sin(\pi x) \sin(\pi y)$$ and note that such $u$ automatically satisfies the boundary condition. Thus is we choose alpha so as to make $u$ satisfy the equation, we are done. For our $u$, we see $$-\triangle u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \alpha \pi^2 \sin(\pi x) \sin (\pi y) + \alpha \pi^2 \sin(\pi x) \sin (\pi y) = 2\alpha \pi^2 \sin(\pi x) \sin(\pi y).$$ Thus choosing $\alpha = 1$ works. Similarly, for the second, we can try $$v(x,y) = \beta \sin(2\pi x) \sin (2\pi y)$$ and $v$ will automatically satisfy the boundary conditions. We see that $$-\triangle v = 8 \beta \pi^2 \sin(2 \pi x) \sin(2 \pi y)$$ so choosing $\beta = 1/8$ will give the solution.